# WebClient - how to ignore a specific HTTP error

Tags: spring-webflux

I'd like to create a Spring WebClient that ignores a specific HTTP error. From the documentation of WebClient.retrieve():

> By default, 4xx and 5xx responses result in a WebClientResponseException. To customize error handling, use ResponseSpec.onStatus(Predicate, Function) handlers.

I want all calls through a WebClient instance to ignore the specific HTTP error. That is why onStatus() is of no use to me (it has to be set per response).

The best I could come up with is this:

```
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().filter((request, next) -> {
            Mono<ClientResponse> response = next.exchange(request);
            response = response.onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class, ex -> {
                return ex.getRawStatusCode() == 418 ? Mono.empty() : Mono.error(ex);
            });
            return response;
        }).build();

        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("https://httpstat.us/418").build().toUri();
        webClient.get().uri(uri).retrieve().toBodilessEntity().block();
```

but it does throw the exception instead of ignoring it (the lambda passed to onErrorResume() is never called).

**Edited:** fixed the mistake pointed out by the first answer.

Answer (score 2):

After extensive debugging of spring-webflux 5.3.4 and with the help of some ideas by Martin Tarjányi, I've come to this as the only possible "solution":

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().filter((request, next) -> {
    return next.exchange(request).flatMap(res -> {
        if (res.rawStatusCode() == HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT.value()) {
            res = res.mutate().rawStatusCode(299).build();
        }
        return Mono.just(res);
    });
}).build();

URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("https://httpstat.us/418").build().toUri();
String body = webClient.get().uri(uri).retrieve().toEntity(String.class).block().getBody();
```

The background: I am migrating some code from RestTemplate to WebClient. The old code looks like this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = ...;
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (response.getRawStatusCode() == HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT.value()) {
            return;
        }
        super.handleError(response);
    }
});

URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("https://httpstat.us/418").build().toUri();
String body = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, String.class).getBody();
```

I believe it is a straightforward and common case.

WebClient is not yet a 100% replacement for RestTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: Turns out this answer doesn't address the core problem of filtering out a specific status code, just addresses a general coding pattern.

---

The reason `onErrorResume` lambda is not called is that `response.onErrorResume` creates a brand new `Mono` and your code does not use the result (i.e. it's not assigned to the `response` variable), so in the end a `Mono` without the `onErrorResume` operator is returned.

Using Project Reactor it's usually a good practice to avoid declaring local `Mono` and `Flux` variables and use a single chain instead. This helps to avoid similar subtle bugs.

```java
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .filter((request, next) -> next.exchange(request)
                        .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class, ex -> ex.getRawStatusCode() == 418 ? Mono.empty() : Mono.error(ex)))
        .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake.
However, even with your version of the code, the onErrorResume lambda is still not called and the exception gets thrown.

Comment: It seems status codes are not errors at that point, so you should rather use `flatMap`: ```WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .filter((request, next) -> next.exchange(request)
                .flatMap(res -> res.rawStatusCode() == 416 ? Mono.empty() : Mono.just(res)))
        .build();```

But this doesn't work either, because WebClient fails on empty `Mono`, so I don't see a solution for this. Sorry.